# Problem with BME280 and long char arrays on Arduino

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino, i2c, arduino-ide

I am trying to fill a char array with 1800 characters (1 and 0) from digital pin 7 (data from a rain gauge) before reading the air pressure from a BME280 using Arduino UNO. The results are printed with Serial.println over USB.

```
#include <Adafruit_BME280.h>
#define DATA 7

Adafruit_BME280 bme;

void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    bme.begin(0x76);
    pinMode(DATA, INPUT);  
}

void loop() 
{ 
   int rmax = 1800;      //1460
   char r[rmax+1];       // changed from r[rmax]
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < rmax; i++)
   {
      if (digitalRead(DATA) == 1)
         r[i] = '1';
      else
         r[i] = '0';
   }
   r[rmax] = '\0';
   Serial.println(r);
   Serial.println(bme.readPressure());
   delay(1000);
}
```

If the size of the array is greater than 1460, the data is not read from BME280, and array is printed without lineshift.
Can anybody tell me why, and what can be done to get succeeded if the size of the array is 1800?

Comment: Array `r` is not large enough. (It is off by one.) `r[rmax] = '\0';` is a buffer overflow.

Comment: Increasing the size to rmax+1 does not help.

Comment: You are running out of RAM. Instead of storing 1800 reading data as `1` or `0`, you could count the rain gauge activation with one integer as `if (digitalRead(DATA) == 1) { int rainGaugeCount++; };`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a stack overflow problem.

As you can see in ATMega328 datasheet [here](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega48A-PA-88A-PA-168A-PA-328-P-DS-DS40002061B.pdf) or [here](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf), you have 2KB RAM only. ATMega328/ATMega328P is usually used as a base MCU for the Arduino UNO board.

To check that, you can make array `char r[rmax];` as static & fix the buffer overflow problem, as Ian told.

Here you can find your code with fixes:

```c
// ...
// you previous code here

// NOTE: next row was added
#define rmax 1800

void loop() 
{ 
   // NOTE: next row was changed
   static char r[rmax + 1];
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < rmax; i++)
   {
      if (digitalRead(DATA) == 1)
         r[i] = '1';
      else
         r[i] = '0';
   }
   r[rmax] = '\0';
   Serial.println(r);
   Serial.println(bme.readPressure());
   delay(1000);
}
```

If you have problems with code compiling, you have a stack overflow problem (RAM ends).

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be omitted by combining groups of 4 bits to hex numbers. This will reduce the size of the char array by a factor of 1/4.

```
char code_bin_to_hex(char bin[])
{
    char hex;
    if (strcmp(bin, "0000") == 0)
        hex= '0';
    else if (strcmp(bin, "0001") == 0)
        hex = '1';
    else if (strcmp(bin, "0010") == 0)
        hex = '2';
    ....

    else if (strcmp(bin, "1110") == 0)
        hex = 'e';
    else if (strcmp(bin, "1111") == 0)
        hex = 'f';
    else
        hex = '?';
    return hex;
}
```